# Jenkins Pipeline Error while trying to send JSON Payload after post success

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, payload

I'm trying to send a custom JSON payload from my pipeline on Jenkins after the last successful stage, like this:

```
  post {
        success {
            script {
                def payload = """
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "SonarQube report from Jenkins Pipeline"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Code was analyzed was successfully.",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Good",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3"
}"""
                httpRequest httpMode: 'POST',
                        acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                        contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                        url: "URL",
                        requestBody: payload
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error

```
Error when executing success post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: schema for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

I'm using the HTTP Request plugin available for Jenkins and the format of the JSON payload is correct for MS Teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually a groovy syntax error. You can easily check this in something like https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ by adding your `def payload = ...` statement.

There are multiple ways to get multiline strings in groovy:

- [triple single quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string)
- [triple double quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string)
- [slashy string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string)
- [dollary slashy string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string)

[Apart from the single quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table), they also have a secondary property which is [interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Notice how in the initial JSON payload, there's a `"$schema"` key? Using triple double quoted strings makes groovy want to find a `schema` variable and use it's value to construct that payload variable.

You have two separate solutions:

1. Use [triple single quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) - just update `"""` to `'''`
2. Escape the variable - just update `"$schema"` to `"\$schema"` (making $ a literal $ instead of it being used as an interpolation prefix)